# Django forms: is_valid doesn't approve of a field value retrieved through Ajax

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I'm using some ajax to fill a custom select box dynamically in my form.
However, when I post the data the **`is_valid`** method doesn't want to validate the submitted value for this field, although it's a valid value from the db, just not retrieved by Django itself.

Here's my initially empty field populated afterwards with Ajax:

```
accompanying_partner = forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
```

It's populated dynamically according to another selected choice field.

Django warns me the value isn't valid.

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow provide filter dataset to form constructor (if it's contained in `data` - that's good), then in the constructor compute actual choices and set `self.fields['accompanying_partner'].choices = actual_choices` to make validation work.